# How to get the insert ID from this ADODB.Recordset?

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to avoid using straight SQL queries in my web app. I looked around and have come to the conclusion that ADO `Recordset`s would be the best or at least safest tool for the job. I need to insert records into a database table. Unfortunately I'm at a loss as to how to get the identity value for the record which was just inserted. Here's a reduction of what I've got now:

```
<%
dim insertID, rs
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "my_table_name", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic

rs.AddNew()

Call m_map_values_to_rs(rs)

rs.Update()

insertID = rs("id")

rs.Close()
rs = Nothing
%>
```

The code I have is successfully inserting the record, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the id field of the `Recordset` to update after the insert. How can I get the identity column value back from this `Recordset`?

**UPDATE** - Here's the solution with regard to the code above.

I had to change the cursor type to `adOpenKeyset` instead of `adOpenForwardOnly`. After I did this the record is automatically updated with the "auto number" field's new value after the insert. However it is ***not*** what you think it is. The value of `rs("id")` doesn't become an integer or even a variant. It becomes some sort of `Automation` type and cannot be evaluated as a number. Nor can CInt() be used directly on that type for some reason. So what you must do is to convert the value to a string and then convert it to an `Int`. Here's how I managed that:

```
insertID = CInt( rs("id") & "" )
```

Thanks to Dee for their answer. It helped immensely.

Comment: thanks for the update - that's valuable information

Comment: Old thread, but rs("id") is a Field object. You should be able to get rs("id").value

Comment: Thanks...was using adOpenDynamic and that wasn't working either.  Changed to adOpenKeyset as you mentioned and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150519073859/http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-get-the-identity/autonumber-value-for-the-row-i-inserted.html) explains the means of getting identity value with example code.

The relevant code snippet is:

```
<% 
    fakeValue = 5 
    set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    conn.open "<conn string>" 
    sql = "INSERT someTable(IntColumn) values(" & fakeValue & ")" & _ 
        VBCrLf & " SELECT @@IDENTITY" 
    set rs = conn.execute(sql) 
    response.write "New ID was " & rs(0) 
    rs.close: set rs = nothing 
    conn.close: set conn = nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen/skimmed that one but apparently I missed the last part's relevancy.

Comment: I ran into an issue with the field value that was returned after this. See question for how I handled that.

Comment: this is why the code should be put in the comment and not linked to an external website

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150519073859/http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-get-the-identity/autonumber-value-for-the-row-i-inserted.html

Comment: Dee can you remove that URL and use the one @Mladen Mihajlovic posted? That url now crashes javascript-enabled browsers with an infinite loop of alert boxes.