# how to insert then select in one visit to the database without using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I want to be able to insert a row into a table and then select the newly created identity and return that to classic asp (JScript) without having to create a stored procedure.  Can it be done?

Basically something like this:

```
...
rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet");
rs.Open("INSERT INTO ...;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() x;", objConn, ...
Response.Write(rs("x").Value);
```

The following works, but amounts to two trips to the database:

```
...
objConn.Execute("INSERT INTO ...
rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet");
rs.Open("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() x;", objConn, ...
Response.Write(rs("x").Value);
```

Comment: Have you tried it and run into problems?

Comment: Yes, the record set is void, it doesn't like it

Comment: That should work. If the record set is void, there may be other configuration issues at work here.

Comment: If I don't include the insert in the recordset but use objConn.execute instead, it works fine, but that's two trips to the database, so no other configuration issues in play

Comment: My old school ADO memory is fuzzy. Don't you need to `MoveFirst` or something to make sure you're on a record?

Comment: Movefirst is not normally needed.  In my case, the recordset is void, so no movefirst available

Comment: Maybe this will help. It's safer from a sql injection standpoint anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506456/how-to-get-the-insert-id-from-this-adodb-recordset

Answer (score 1):

You could try a direct call to the stored procedure and store the results in an array like so:

```vb
dim rs, arr, sql
sql = "EXEC myProc"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
rs_temp.open sql, application("CONN_DISCHARGE"),3,3,1
if not (rs.bof and rs.eof) then runsql=rs.getrows
rs.close
set rs = nothing
```

Within your stored procedure you can do whatever you want...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        myTable
    SET 
        myField = 42

    SELECT 
        myField 
    FROM 
        myTable 
    WHERE 
        someCondition = 1
END
```

-- EDIT --

For a more complete version of the ASP function [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731410/classic-asp-for-each-loop-terminating-too-early/16731632#16731632).  Note that you'll have to include this in a separate file with a VB Script specifier at the top (not JScript) for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are receiving the number of rows affected by the insert first, then the identity value. You can either use `SET NOCOUNT ON` or use `rs.MoveNext` before accessing the recordset.
e.g.

```
   rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet");
    rs.Open("SET NOCOUNT ON;INSERT INTO ...;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() x;", objConn, ...
    Response.Write(rs("x").Value);
```

or

```
rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet");
rs.Open("INSERT INTO ...;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() x;", objConn, ...
rs.MoveNext()
Response.Write(rs("x").Value);
```